# what should be the null hypothesis?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, mathematical-statistics, experiment-design

conduct a test hypothesis to show that it takes longer for people with average fitness to successfully complete physical therapy as compared to those with above average physical fitness. Test at $\alpha$=0.01 level of significance.
here $\mu_2$=average fitness,$\mu_3$=above average physical fitness.

in my view

null hypothesis $H_0$:$\mu_2$>$\mu_3$
alternative hypothesis $H_1$:$\mu_2$$\ngtr$$\mu_3$

am i right?

Comment: Is this a homework question or self-study question?  If so, it should be tagged accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the null hypothesis represents the "skeptical choice". In this problem the skeptical choice is to assume that average fitness **does not** affect the physical therapy time.

Hence, I would cast this problem as a hypothesis test on the difference of two means.

$H_0: \mu_2 - \mu_3 = 0$ and $H_1: \mu_2 - \mu_3 > 0$